# How a function can set and get information from a struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct

I written the following code which I am trying to set and to get information from a struct via get and set functions. However, when I compile and run the program it doesn't show the information which it gets from input. Where is my fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Information{
    int _id;
    char* _name;
    char* _family;
} Information;

void setInformation(Information* arg_struct){
    printf("What is your name? ");
    scanf("%s %s", arg_struct->_name, arg_struct->_family);
    printf("What is your id? ");
    scanf("%d", &arg_struct->_id);
}

void getInformation(Information* arg_struct){
    printf("Your name is %s %s.\n", arg_struct->_name, arg_struct->_family);
    printf("Your id is %d.\n", arg_struct->_id);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    Information *obj = malloc(sizeof(Information));

    setInformation(obj);
    getInformation(obj);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you invoke an UB because `_name` & `_family` are pointers that point to memory you don't own (because you haven't `malloced` it)

try changing it to

```
typedef struct Information{
  int _id;
  char _name[SOME_SIZE_1];
  char _family[SOME_SIZE_2];
}Information;`
```

Or, if you want to stay with pointers instead of arrays, you should malloc it before using the pointers, so in your set function, add 2 malloc statements:

```
void setInformation(Information* arg_struct){
  arg_struct->_name = malloc(SOME_SIZE_1);
  arg_struct->_family = malloc(SOME_SIZE_2);
  printf("What is your name? ");
  scanf("%s %s", arg_struct->_name, arg_struct->_family);
  printf("What is your id? ");
  scanf("%d", &arg_struct->_id);
}
```

but if you are allocating memory, don't forget to free it when you are done